# React importing function

Tags: reactjs

I have component with function `dateBuilder` inside, which I use to get the current date.

```
import React from 'react';
import './WeatherBox.css'
import { Icons } from '../../icons';


const dateBuilder = (d) => {
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

    let day = days[d.getDay()];
    let date = d.getDate();
    let month = months[d.getMonth()];
    let year = d.getFullYear();

    return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`
}

const WeatherBox = ({currentWeatherResult}) => {
        return (
            <div className="locationDate">
                <span>{currentWeatherResult.location}</span>
                <span>{dateBuilder(new Date())}</span>
                <span>{currentWeatherResult.temp}°C</span>
                <img src={Icons[currentWeatherResult.sky]} alt={Icons[currentWeatherResult.sky]} />   
            </div>
        )

}

export default WeatherBox;
```

So, if I want to move this function to another direction as a helper, how can I export it to any component I want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateBuilder is pure javascript function, no need to export it as component. You can export it as javascript function.

```
const dateBuilder = (d) => {
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

    let day = days[d.getDay()];
    let date = d.getDate();
    let month = months[d.getMonth()];
    let year = d.getFullYear();

    return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`
}

export default dateBuilder;
```

You can use it in the following way

```
import React from 'react';
import './WeatherBox.css'
import { Icons } from '../../icons';
import dateBuilder from './dateBuilder';

const WeatherBox = ({currentWeatherResult}) => {
        return (
            <div className="locationDate">
                <span>{currentWeatherResult.location}</span>
                <span>{dateBuilder(new Date())}</span>
                <span>{currentWeatherResult.temp}°C</span>
                <img src={Icons[currentWeatherResult.sky]} alt={Icons[currentWeatherResult.sky]} />   
            </div>
        )

}

export default WeatherBox;
```

To addition to your question, you are trying to manually format the date. There are some good packages available in js like moment to easily format date.

You can refer [this](https://momentjs.com/) or [this](https://thecodebarbarian.com/formatting-javascript-dates-with-moment-js.html) for more info about moment.